# Reducing three while loops into one (Java)

Tags: java, while-loop

This code itself works fine, but I need to reduce the three while loops into one, and I cannot seem to get it syntactically correct.

```
while (numY == numX) {
    System.out.print("The numbers are the same");
    break;
}
while (numY < numX) {
    int lesserY;
    lesserY = numY;
    int greaterX;
    greaterX = numX;
    System.out.printf("%d is the greater than %d", greaterX, lesserY);
    break;
}
while (numY > numX) {
    int greaterY;
    greaterY = numY;
    int lesserX;
    lesserX = numX;
    System.out.printf("%d is the greater than %d", greaterY, lesserX);
    break;
}
```

Comment: why not use `if`/`else` instead of `while` (-`break`)?

Comment: Why do you want a `while` loop? You use `break` for each one. :) Just convert them to zero `while`s.

Comment: Sure, `while(true) { /* if / else if / else */ break;}` ! (this is sarcasm)

Comment: `while (numY == numX)` without changing either `numY` or `numX` will spin forever. I'm not sure you're using the correct construct here.

Answer (score 3):

Why you simple don't use any while because you use it only one time and use `if(..)else` like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numY = 5, numX = 6;
    if (numY == numX) {
        System.out.print("The numbers are the same");

    } else if (numY < numX) {
        int lesserY;
        lesserY = numY;
        int greaterX;
        greaterX = numX;
        System.out.printf("%d is the greater than %d", greaterX, lesserY);
    } else if (numY > numX) {
        int greaterY;
        greaterY = numY;
        int lesserX;
        lesserX = numX;
        System.out.printf("%d is the greater than %d", greaterY, lesserX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking more into the different control structures in most programming languages. Loops are meant to be used when you need to repeat an action so-and-so many times. In each of your cases, you break from the while loop immediately. Look into `if` / `else if` / `else` blocks and you'll find that you can reduce your program to a single `if`, `else if`, `else` construct.

You have three possible outcomes:
1> `numY == numX` 2> `numY < numX` 3> `numY > numX`

These branching choices can be expressed like so:

```
if (condition1) {
    // ...
} else if (condition2) {
    // ...
} else if (condition3) {
    // ...
}
```

What is nice with your particular conditions is that if you know that `numY == numX` and `numY < numX` are false, then you know that the only other possible choice `numY > numX` is true.

That means that you can just use an `else` to represent "if all other conditions are false, do this".

```
if (condition1) {
    // ...
} else if (condition2) {
    // ...
} else { // only if condition3 is true when condition1 and condition2 are false
    // ...
}
```